# Enhancing code coverage after using JaCoCo by writing unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jacoco

I am working with JaCoCo and JUnit testing. There is a public method in a class which makes calls to two other private methods. My understanding is that after code coverage report shows that certain methods have not been covered then I can write a JUnit test to test those methods and then code coverage should increase. Is that correct? I am writing a JUnit test to test the public method which in turn makes call to a private method. Whatever is required to be passed to private method, that I am passing, either by creating it or mocking it, but code coverage does not increase. Any suggestions?

Comment: let's see some code.  Are you sure the parameters make the code branch to the private methods as you expect?

Comment: If Jacoco shows your code as not covered, then you probably didn't cover them. Without code, hard to say why.